# Пошел на базар за курицей или по курицу

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно сказать: "пошел на базар за курицей" или "по курицу"?

Answer (score 3):

Нормативным является "за курицей".
Само сочетание "по курицу" звучит очень странно.
В народной речи можно часто слышать "[пошел] по грибы", "по воду" и подобное, но только со множественным числом или с неисчислимым существительным. Более того, нормативность подобных конструкций ограничивается обычно  употреблением в отношении "даров природы" (природных ресурсов) минерального и растительного происхождения.

"По курицу" не подходит ни по каким признакам. Даже в народной речи такое может прозвучать разве что на украинско-русском суржике, да и то скорее - на западном.

В русском (строго литературном, разговорном, даже диалектном и просторечном в большинстве проявлений) - **"за курицей"**.

//====================
К разговору о лисе с курами. Надо же, нашел подтверждение своему языковому чутью. Второй винительный тут.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvgod.jpg]

Прямая ссылка на картинку (если не видно выше)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvgod.jpg

Источник
http://ethnosport.ru/files/nmdttp-tge-vsevolod-igry-sssr.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Пошел на базар **за курицей**.

1) Основным вариантом предлога с таким значением является **предлог ЗА** (кем-чем). Указывает на лицо, предмет и т.п., которые нужно достать, добыть, привести и т.п. **Послать за врачом. Заехать за вещами. Идти за водой.**

2) **Предлог ПО** употребляется в значении предлог ЗА, причем это **разговорная** или народно-поэтическая речь, да и тематика вполне определенная: **Разг**. Употр. при указании предмета, лица и т.п., которые необходимо достать, добыть, привести и т.п.; соответствует по значению предлогу за. Пойти в лес **по грибы, по ягоды**. Ходить **по воду**.

**Пример**

Просто позвал меня к себе на квартиру, а жена его в это время **пошла на базар за поросенком**, ― было рождество. [А. И. Куприн. Яма (1909-1915)]

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (почему мы ходим "по грибы, по ягоды и по воду")**
Фразеологизм «пойти по грибы» очень старый, появился в те времена, когда люди были близки к природе и тщательно подбирали слова, чтобы фраза ненароком не стала пророческой, судьбоносной. **Пойти за грибами означало заблудиться**, в буквальном смысле идти по лесу, **следуя за выросшими грибами**. Ведь грибница располагается спиралью, а по спирали ох как далеко можно уйти и заплутать.  «По воду» из той же серии. Раньше воду набирали в реках и ручьях и пойти за водой означало пойти следом по течению реки.

[Как правильно - в лес по грибы или в лес за грибами? Почему? | bolshoyvopros.ru](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1629540-kak-pravilno-v-les-po-griby-ili-v-les-za-gribami-pochemu.html)

Comment: *Употр. при указании предмета, лица и т.п., которые необходимо достать, добыть, привести и т.п* - можете привести пример подобного употребленияв отношении ***лица***?! И вообще чего-либо за пределами  даров леса (грибов, ягод, орехов) и воды?! Где вы такие формулировки откапываете? Если не ваши, то хоть ссылочку бы давали...

Comment: Словарь Кузнецова на Грамоте.ру. А примеры можно в сказках найти: "испугался он, что черт пришел исключительно по его душу".

Comment: Не Кузнецовым единым, но элемент "наудачу" он верно отметил. По яблоки в чужой сад, зарекалась лиса по кур ходить (русская поговорка), пошёл медведь по малину (русская скороговорка)...

Comment: *зарекалась лиса по кур ходить (русская поговорка)* - что-то очень сомнительно грамматически. "По куры" должно быть. Это второй винительный, собирательный (ср. выйти в люди, забрить в солдаты) . Все остальное попадает в разряд "дары природы". И какая удача в том, чтобы пойти по воду"?!

Comment: И все-таки именно так, "по кур". Ссылка сюда не влезет, смотрите "по русскихъ князихъ" - неоднократно цитируемая по Карамзину форма. Апресян тоже дает "пойти+ВИН". Гуглится на *семантика "по воду"*.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: за курицей.

Как мне кажется, предлог ПО заменяет предлог  ЗА в тех случаях, когда предмет (любой) **нужно не пойти и взять или купить,** а **достать или найти**. В этом случае субъект действия не уверен в успехе или проявляет суеверие, боится "сглазить". Поэтому используется предлог ПО со значением **направленности** действия, а не предлог ЗА со значением его гарантированной **завершенности**.

Answer (score 0):

Этот ответ устарел - см. другой, данный месяцем позже.

"По курицу" - выражение устаревшее, архаичное, но исторически правильное.
Вот насчет "по кур" или "по куры" - есть большое сомнение в адекватности источника.

Там исторически форма обычного винительного. "По брата", "по коней". Это не второй винительный.
Наличие одушевленной формы в единственном числе исключает второй винительный вовсе, а выбор между "по кур" и "по куры" заставляет говорить об обычном винительном (если "по кур") или вообще (если "по куры") некоем "третьем винительном", который в единственном числе совпадает с обычным винительным, а во множественном - со вторым винительным ("включительным"). По счастью, второй вариант вроде бы не подтверждается историческими документами, говорить о третьем винительном пока преждевременно. Поэтому скорее всего - **"по кур"**.