# Ехать ЗА или ПО: как правильно?

Tags: предлоги

Возник спор с коллегой.

Мой вариант: "На Кипр по лицензию, конечно, никто не едет".
Его вариант: "На Кипр за лицензией, конечно, никто не едет".

Рассудите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Коллега прав(а). ***Поедет за лицензией***.

Формы с предлогом ПО в значении цели сейчас совершенно непродуктивны и сохранились исключительно в выражениях "идти/ходить по грибы/ягоды/воду".
Впрочем, даже в подобных выражениях они, судя по всему, применимы исключительно к сбору диких природных ресурсов или охоте, собирательству. В огород "ПО" уже не ходят.

Лицензия уж никак к природным ресурсам не относится.

Вообще вопрос с этим предлогом ПО неоднократно обсуждался.
Вот например:
[Пошел на базар за курицей или по курицу](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/426664)
Почитайте там ответы.

===UPD

Хороший вопрос задали в отношении "(Пришел) по вашу душу". Как с ним-то быть? 
Пока не знаю. Может быть, это вообще иное значение предлога, а может, восходит к черту, охотящемуся за душами введенных во искушение. Буду думать.

Comment: Спасибо, нашла ваш ответ, полезно

Comment: А какъ же «по Вашу душу?»

Comment: @АлексейГригорьевич  Хороший вопрос, спасибо. Полагаю, что он имеет в основе образ черта, охотящегося **по души** введенных во искушение. То есть исходным посылкам не противоречит. Если чего надумаю по этому повуду - доплню ответ. Но вы меняч заставили пересмотреть отношение к формулировке  ответа по ссылке. Там я категорически не соглашался с тем, что можно употреблять по отношению к лицам. Надо будет и там отметиться.